# Please help me to understand the below javascript code and usage of outputpanel. step by step since i'm new to salesforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript

```
<script>
function toggleContacts(className){
    elem = document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0];
    if(elem.style.display == 'none')
        elem.style.display = 'block';
    else
        elem.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>

<apex:form >

    <apex:repeat value="{!accs}" var="a">

        <apex:pageBlock title="{!a.Name}">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <input type="button" onclick="toggleContacts('tbl-{!a.id}');" value="Show/Hide contacts" class="btn" /> 
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:outputField value="{!a.Phone}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="tbl-{!a.id}" style="display:none;">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!a.Contacts}" var="c">
                <apex:facet name="header">Contacts</apex:facet>
                <apex:column value="{!c.Name}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:repeat>

</apex:form>
```

Comment: The original topic: [how to display parent and child records in visualforce page with seperate pageblocktables using classes?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24235/how-to-display-parent-and-child-records-in-visualforce-page-with-seperate-pagebl)

Comment: bonus points for trying the on-page `twist` function

Comment: @user5301 can you paste your whole code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JS function **toggleContacts()** accepts className as argument. It then searches the DOM for the element with the specified class (e.g. if a function is called with argument "green-panel", like so: **toggleContacts("green-panel")**, the function will browse the DOM for element with class="green-panel"), examines whether the retrieved element is visible or hidden on the page and switches it's visibility accordingly (if it was previously visible, after the call it will be hidden, and vice versa).

The outputPanel in the repeat block is marked with class comprised of prefix **"tbl-"** and postfix of and Id of the record currently being rendered. In practice, this will result in HTML output resembling something like:

```
<div class="tbl-001g000000ABVGd" style="display:none;">
...
</div>
```

The button within the same repeat block calls aforementioned JS function with the argument same as the css class name built for the output panel, for the purpose of JS function being able to identify and find the targeted HTML element and change it's visibility.

Comment: Thank you for giving me such a good description. And what does it mean 'elem = document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0]; '

Comment: With `document.getElementsByClassName(...)` you can access page elements per class name. With `[0]` only the fist element with given class name will be taken. Read more about [HTML DOM Elements](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_document.asp)

Comment: "elem" is just a variable, could be even defined as a local (within the scope of the function) to avoid confusion... look at it like:
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0]